# Set approval status of a list item to pending while retaining the approved version

Tags: event-receivers, sharepoint-server, content-approval

I have a site with multiple lists which are linked to each other.
When I update an item(edit / approve) in one list, the approval status of the corresponding items in the other lists also should be updated accordingly.

I was able to achieve it using an event receiver on `ItemUpdated` event, and the item approval is reflected fine.

However, when I further edit an item in any list, the item of course goes into `pending` status, and I am copying this moderation status to the other lists. But in doing so, the approved version in the other lists are lost; whereas the item in the source list still has an approved item.

This is causing an inconsistency for me because I have an approved item in one list, but not in the other lists. Because of this, `Viewers` see the item in the 'source list', but when they try to check the other lists, they get an error.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to solve the issue like below:

```
if (spiCurrentItem != null)
{
    spiCurrentItem ["Title"] = spModifiedItem.Title;
    if (spModifiedItem.ModerationInformation.Status == SPModerationStatusType.Approved)
    {
        spiCurrentItem.ModerationInformation.Status = SPModerationStatusType.Approved;
    }
    spiCurrentItem.Update();
}
```

The block where I check for the `Approved` status will set the specific items in the other lists as Approved, if the modifiedItem has the status as Approved.

Otherwise, a simple `Update` operation is done on the item, which will create a new version, while retaining the Approved version.